# Remove Value when Checkbox is unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

im trying to remove a value when a checkbox is unchecked.
My Code:

```
var words = new List<string>();

if (ckbAnswer1.Checked)
   words.Add(" -A,");

if (ckbAnswer2.Checked)
   words.Add("B,");

if (ckbAnswer3.Checked)
   words.Add("C");

treeView1.SelectedNode.Text +=   treeView1.SelectedNode.Text +string.Join(" ", words);
```

Return  `Question 1 - A,B,C`, but, say i want to uncheck "A", which should remove it from `Question 1 - A,B,C`. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou should subscribe on `CheckedChanged` event and inside method check:

```
private void CheckBoxA_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (checkboxA.Checked)
    {
        words.Add("word");
    }
    else
    {
        words.Remove("word");            
    }
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "Question 1 - ";
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += string.Join(" ", words);          
}
```

Comment: I have tried `
            if (ckbAnswer1.Checked)
            {
                words.Add("A,");
                
            }
            else
            {
                words.Remove("A,");
            }

            treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += string.Join(" ", words);` - it did not work/

Comment: Do you want to remove this word from treeView.Text?

Comment: Yes, so the  treeView.Text was initially Question 1- A,B,C it will be now Question 1 - B,C .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use some key instead of just text based questions.

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> words = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>();

ckbAnswer1.Tag = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

if (ckbAnswer1.Checked)
    questions.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(ckbAnswer1.Tag, "A"));
 else//Unchecked
   words.Remove(words.Where(kv => kv.Key == ckbAnswer1.Tag));


treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + string.Join(", ", words.Select(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign this `CheckChanged` event to each `Checkbox`:

```
private void ckbAnswer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   UpdateNode();
}
```

And then add the method:

```
private void UpdateNode()
{
   var words = new List<string>();
   if (ckbAnswer1.Checked)
   {
      words.Add("A");
   }
   if (ckbAnswer2.Checked)
   {
      words.Add("B");
   }
   if (ckbAnswer3.Checked)
   {
      words.Add("C");
   }
   var answers = " - none";
   if (words.Count > 0) {
      answers = " - " +  string.Join(", ", words);
   }
   treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString() + answers;
}
```

This line should be added to where you initially populate the TreeView:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
```

That should do what you are after.

The 'tricky' part is ensuring you keep a copy of the original Node.Text.

Comment: Thanks for the help , i tried it  . It returns `Question 1 Question 1A `

Comment: @AndroidAL Hi. I see the problem. You need to move the `treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;` to the place in your code where you initially populate the treeview nodes. I've also made a small edit to the last line of code - I made a typo.